# Make a tuple from 3 1-d numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have 3 1-d numpy arrays a, b, c and I want to construct an array of tuples where each tuple is (a[i],b[i],c[i]) (so a column of each array a, b, c)), what is the most fastest and efficient way to do this (without iteration)?

example:

```html
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]

#resulting tuple array would be
tup = [(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9)]
```

Comment: Those are not numpy arrays, those are *lists*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply `zip` them:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([4,5,6])
>>> c = np.array([7,8,9])
>>> 
>>> list(zip(a,b,c))
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

The `list` call is required only for Python 3.

As @piRSquared notes, you can go a tad faster with `zip` by first converting your arrays to lists:

```
In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: list(zip(a,b,c))
    ...:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 µs per loop

In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: list(zip(*map(np.ndarray.tolist, [a, b, c])))
    ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 µs per loop
```

The gains should increase with the size of the arrays.

Comment: **If** `a`, `b`, and `c` are `np.array`s... you'd get a smidge faster with `list(zip(*map(np.ndarray.tolist, [a, b, c])))`

Comment: @piRSquared Oh nice, just did the timings.